# RSpec generated test what does "assigns the requested experience_level as @experience_level" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying get this spec to pass, but I don't know what it means. Here is the full spec. The **second** example is the one that is failing.

```
describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested experience_level" do
        experience_level = ExperienceLevel.create! valid_attributes
        # Assuming there are no other experience_levels in the database, this
        # specifies that the ExperienceLevel created on the previous line
        # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are
        # submitted in the request.
        ExperienceLevel.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({ "name" => "MyString" })
        put :update, {:id => experience_level.to_param, :experience_level => { "name" => "MyString" }}
      end

      it "assigns the requested experience_level as @experience_level" do
        experience_level = ExperienceLevel.create!(name: 'test'), valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => experience_level.to_param, :experience_level => valid_attributes}
        assigns(:experience_level).should eq(experience_level)
      end

      it "redirects to the experience_level" do
        experience_level = ExperienceLevel.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => experience_level.to_param, :experience_level => valid_attributes}
        response.should redirect_to(experience_level)
      end
    end
```

Here is the message in the terminal:

```
1) ExperienceLevelsController PUT update with valid params assigns the requested experience_level as @experience_level
     Failure/Error: assigns(:experience_level).should eq(experience_level)

       expected: [#<ExperienceLevel id: 1, name: "test", description: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05", updated_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05">, {"name"=>"MyString"}]
            got: #<ExperienceLevel id: 1, name: "MyString", description: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05", updated_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05">

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
       -[#<ExperienceLevel id: 1, name: "test", description: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05", updated_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05">,
       - {"name"=>"MyString"}]
       +#<ExperienceLevel id: 1, name: "MyString", description: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05", updated_at: "2013-10-10 20:40:05">

     # ./spec/controllers/experience_levels_controller_spec.rb:100:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: You are setting up experience level with a name of test, but in the call to put using valid_attributes where presumably the name is MyString?

Comment: I thought that was the problem at first as well, but changing test to MyString doesn't cause it to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement in your second example:

```
experience_level = ExperienceLevel.create!(name: 'test'), valid_attributes
```

is the same as:

```
experience_level = [ExperienceLevel.create!(name: 'test'), valid_attributes]
```

In other words, it's creating an array from the two comma separated values on the right hand side of the assignment operator and assigning that array to `experience_level`. This is at least one reason why your test is failing.